# VIACEP não achou a variável CEP para retornar ao resultado em PHP

Tags: php, libcurl, cep

Olá,

Apenas a pesquisa de CEP para achar a cidade e o estado funciona, mas a pesquisa de cidade e estado [e bairro] para achar o CEP não funciona porque no JSON, a variável CEP (`$result->cep`) está dentro das chaves da classe numérica e não existe classe de estado-cidade.

Eis em PHP:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{

 function webClient($url)
 {
     $ch = curl_init();

     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
     curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

     $data = curl_exec($ch);

     curl_close($ch);

     return $data;
 }

 $descubra = $_POST['descubra'];

 switch ($descubra)
 {
  case "lugar":
   $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
   $estado = $_POST['estado'];
   $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
   $url = sprintf('https://viacep.com.br/ws/%s/%s/%s/json/ ', $estado, $cidade, $bairro);
   $result = json_decode(webClient($url));
   echo $result->cep;
   break;

  case "ceplocal":
   $cep    = $_POST['cep'];
   $url = sprintf('https://viacep.com.br/ws/%s/json/ ', $cep);
   $result = json_decode(webClient($url));
   echo $result->localidade;
   echo $result->uf;
   break;

  default:
    echo "Inválido!";
 }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Na verdade seu código está funcionando, note o que diz a documentação sobre pesquisa por endereço:

> *O resultado será ordenado pela proximidade do nome do logradouro e possui limite máximo de 50 (cinquenta) CEPs.*

Então sua pesquisa irá buscar todas as ruas que contém `X` palavra, e irá retornar um `array`, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
$cidade = 'Americana';
$estado = 'SP';
$bairro = 'Frezzarin';
```

Terá o retorno:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cep] => 13467-019
            [logradouro] => Praça José Frezzarin
            [complemento] => 
            [bairro] => Jardim São José
            [localidade] => Americana
            [uf] => SP
            [unidade] => 
            [ibge] => 3501608
            [gia] => 1650
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [cep] => 13465-789
            [logradouro] => Praça Marcílio Frezzarin
            [complemento] => 
            [bairro] => Vila Frezzarin
            [localidade] => Americana
            [uf] => SP
            [unidade] => 
            [ibge] => 3501608
            [gia] => 1650
        )
    ...
)
```

Para usar o `echo` tem que informar o índice `$result[0]->cep` e assim por diante.

> Podes ver funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ProudDeliriousPriorities)

Comment: eu também utilizo o CEP Aberto e observo que ele não possui `array`. Verifica: https://repl.it/@Gustavo_Benedit/NaoExisteArrayNoCEPAberto.